# How to fix error uninitialized constant error in ruby when using rake console?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, command-line-interface

I am using my rake console pry session to test out a class I have created for a CLI application I am making. Everytime I type "City.new" I expect to see nil attributes as instructed but I get a:

```
City.new
NameError: uninitialized constant City
```

What are common reasons for getting this error if I defined my class in another file. How can I fix this issue?
Thanks so much

Comment: You need to make sure you are loading your application. Is this a Rails app or something else? Please show your rake file and tell us what is the entry point of your application, e.g. is there a file you can load which will then require the rest of your files?

Comment: @funguy : Ruby does not know what `City` is. Please show the complete code, in particular the part where you defined this constant.

Comment: Did you required the class? With require 'city'

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue, I had not generated the controller for City model. Try that to see if will work